# Number of homomorphisms between two arbitrary groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism, permutation-cycles

How many homomorphisms are there from $A_5$ to $S_4$ ?

This is how I tried to solve it.

If there is a homomorphism from $A_5$ to $S_4$ , then order of element of $S_4$ should divide the order of its preimage. Now what are the possible order of elements in $S_4$.1,2,3 and 4. Since $A_5$ contains (12345), which is of order 5.. what could be image of (12345). Definitely Identity element which is of order 1. Similarly all 5 cycles must be mapped to identity.  There are 24 elements of 5 cycles. 24 elements out of 60 are mapped to identity .. now only two types of homomorphisms are possible. either 30:1mapping  or 60:1 mapping.  Consider (12)(34) which belongs to $A_5$. It's image can be element of order 2 or identity.there are 15 elements of order 2 . suppose these 15 elements are mapped to some element 'g' of order 2 of $S_4$, you need another 15 elements to get mapped to 'g' to have 30 :1 mapping. Other type of elements left in $A_5$ is of order 3. None of them can be mapped to g. hence 15 elements of order 2 should be mapped to identity .. so ,  (24+15=39) elements mapped to identity.As mentioned earlier it should be 30 :1 or 60:1 mapping. So it must be 60:1 mapping.Hence a trivial homomorphism. Answer is 1.

I wanted to know is there any other technique which can be used to find number of homomorphism in the above question ?
In general, how to find number of homomorphism  between any two arbitrary groups ?

Comment: $A_5$ is simple.

Comment: So $A_5$ is simple and since order of $A_5$ is greater than order of $S_4$ , It cannot be one-one mapping. So trivial

Comment: The question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361745/strategy-for-determining-the-number-of-homomorphisms-between-two-groups?rq=1) already.

Comment: List all the functions between the two sets of group elements and count which ones are group homomorphisms.

Comment: The exact number of homomorphisms between two arbitrary groups is rarely of much interest, although for some reason it seems to be a popular homework problem. It is of course interesting to know hwether two groups are isomorphic, or whether one is isomorphic to a subgroup or quotient of the other, but the exact number of homomorphisms has no particular significance.

Comment: @DerekHolt Just to let you know, these types of questions are asked in competitive exams in India for scolarship for PhD etc, and they carry ideas as is shown by the answer below, not rigorous calculations. I do get your point, they have no particular significance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Suppose $f:A_5 \to S_4$ be a homomorphism. Then $\ker f$ is a normal subgroup of $A_5$. But $A_5$ is simple, so $$\ker f \in \Big\{ \{e\},A_5\Big\}$$

- $\ker f=\{e\}$ implies $$A_5/\{e\} \sim f(A_5)$$ and so $f(A_5)$ is a subgroup of order $60$ in $S_4$, which is not possible in $S_4$.
- $\ker f=A_5$ implies $f$ is trivial

Hence $$\Big\vert\{f \;\vert  \;f:A_5  \to S_4 \;\text{is a homomorphism} \}\Big\vert=1$$

---

For finding homomorphism $f$ for arbitraay two groups, use the following facts:

- $\vert f(g) \vert$ divides $\vert g \vert$ where $g$ belong to the domain with $\vert g \vert < \infty$ [this is useful for finite groups]
- $f(g^n)=[f(g)]^n$
- List all normal subgroups of domain and use first isomorphism theorem

Comment: very nice answer

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on another property of $A_5$, other than its simplicity, to get that the only homomorphism from $A_5$ to $S_4$ is the trivial one, namely the fact that $A_5$ has no subgroups of order $30$, $20$ and $15$ (see e.g. [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_group:A5)). In fact, a homomorphism $\varphi\colon A_5\to S_4$ is equivalent to a $A_5$-action on the set $X:=\{1,2,3,4\}$. By the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem and the fact that the set of orbits forms a partition of $X$, the stabilizers can only have orders $60/k$, for $1\le k\le 4$; but the stabilizers are subgroups of the group which acts, and hence, by the abovementioned property of $A_5$, the only option $k=1$ is actually allowed (for every $i=1,2,3,4$). So, all the stabilizers must coincide with the whole $A_5$ and the only sought homomorphism has kernel $\bigcap_{i=1}^4{\rm{Stab}}(i)=A_5$, which precisely means that all the elements of $A_5$ are mapped to ${()}_{S_4}$.