# How to determine all homomorphisms regarding two groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

I am confused of what actually it means to find all the homomorphisms between lets say Zn to itself or any other group. I keep confusing it with the idea of finding all the automorphisms ( i know that any automorphism is determined by the image of 1, basically it maps a generator to a generator so the number of auto morphisms in Zn is gonna be phi(n) ) but for homomorphisms I need to know whats the process in order to find any homomorphism between two groups, what do i really need to know ? I have seen different cases while trying to find them, one where the map is onto, and the other where it's just "to", what's the difference and what properties i can use which can make it easier to find them, will properties of homomorphism differ if the groups were not cyclic?

Comment: Have you looked at [either](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361745/strategy-for-determining-the-number-of-homomorphisms-between-two-groups?rq=1) of [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617497/finding-all-homomorphisms-between-two-groups-couple-of-questions?rq=1) answers? They are very similar questions to yours, and knowing why they don't answer your question will help us help you ^_^

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I saw this question already didnt understand a thing in it, the answers given were a bit complex for me, because i dont really know how to  use relations to find homomorphisms,  i was looking for something simpler, like using properties of homomorphisms, and trying to understand better about homomorphic images? Like for instance i read a question that said Z6 and Z8 are homomorphic images of a group i don't remember what group but, anyways i didn't understand what to make out of it and what's the relation between homomorphic images and homomorphisms itself ?

Answer (score 1):

Determining homomorphisms between two groups is not usually an easy thing: one very simple answer for finite groups is to map the generators "coherently". Easier said than done!
But, luckily, to determine a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ to any other group $G$, we do not have to do much! We just have to map a generator coherently! 
$\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is a cyclic group generated by $1_{n}$. Hence any homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_{n} \to G$ is determined by $\phi(1_{n})$ (if you know where $1_{n}$ goes to, then you know where $1_{n}+1_{n}$ goes to, and so on!). Now, we know that $n \phi(1_{n})=\phi(0_{n})=e_{G}$. Hence $\phi(1_n)$ must have order dividing $n$. Pick any element of $G$ whose order divides $n$ (such an element exists, $e_{G}$) and call it $h$. Show that the map $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_{n} \to G$, $\phi([k])=g^k$ is a WELL DEFINED homomorphism of groups. If $G$ is finite, you can look for elements of order dividing gcd(n,|G|), but I will leave that for you to think about!

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me, i actually had a very particular question in my mind, which i remembered after reading ur answer,  which is since generator maps to a generator, from Z12 to Z30, taking 1 to be a generator of z12 then shouldn't its image be a generator of z30 also,finding all the possible generators in z30 gives me different homomorphisms basically different functions, but since i am not sure if the given homomorphism is onto,i can't use this method right? Only when it says its onto,i can determine the homomorphisms just by guessing the possibilities of generators

Comment: @HaneenHussam, the answer explains that the generator of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ doesn't need to map to a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$; it maps to an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ whose order divides $12$.